# mulitiple audio files javascript on single page

Tags: javascript, wordpress, html5-audio

So I found a snippet of code for a quick audio play button 
https://siongui.github.io/2012/10/12/javascript-toggle-sound-onclick/. I want incorporate multiple audio files but on page load, the audio buttons I created only play the last audio file.
`enter code here`

  Play Audio


  
Your browser does not support this audio format.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleSound() {
  var audioElem = document.getElementById('creditCardFem');
  if (audioElem.paused)
    audioElem.play();
  else
    audioElem.pause();
}

function toggleSoun() {
  var audioCreditM = document.getElementById('creditCardMa');
  if (audioCreditM.paused)
    audioCreditM.play();
  else
    audioCreditM.pause();
}

</script>

<div class="audioPlayer">
<button id="player" type="button"
  onclick="javascript:toggleSound();">
  Play Audio
</button>
<audio id="creditCardFem">
  <source src="http://www.smartaction.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Financial_Services_Credit_Card_Payment_Female_Inbound.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support this audio format.
</audio>
</div>

<div class="audioPlayer">
<button id="player" type="button"
  onclick="javascript:toggleSoun();">
  Play Audio
</button>
<audio id="creditCardMa">
  <source src=#">
Your browser does not support this audio format.
</audio>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like only one audio file is linked to in this code.

`<audio id="creditCardMa">` has no reference in its `<source src="#">` child.